# Convert a string with hex value of a very big number

Tags: java, hex, biginteger

I am trying to convert string 9C72E0FA11C2E6A8 to decimal value:

```
             String strHexNumber = "9C72E0FA11C2E6A8";
             Long decimalNumber = Long.parseLong(strHexNumber, 16);
             System.out.println("Hexadecimal number converted to decimal number");
             System.out.println("Decimal number is : " + decimalNumber);
```

I expected to get value `11273320181906204328`, but I got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9C72E0FA11C2E6A8"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:592)
    at ConvertHexToDecimalExample.main(ConvertHexToDecimalExample.java:22)
```

How can I convert hex to decimal in Java?

Thank you!

Comment: The number is clearly much larger than a long, so using `parseLong` won't work. Try [`BigInteger(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String,%20int)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String,%20int)) 
pass the String value  as argument and give the radix as parameter

```
String strHexNumber = "9C72E0FA11C2E6A8";
BigInteger mySuperBigInteger = new BigInteger(strHexNumber , 16);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Java API document for BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String,%20int)) :

> ```
> public BigInteger(String val, int radix)
> ```
>
> Translates the String representation of a BigInteger in the specified
>   radix into a BigInteger. The String representation consists of an
>   optional minus or plus sign followed by a sequence of one or more
>   digits in the specified radix. The character-to-digit mapping is
>   provided by Character.digit. The String may not contain any extraneous
>   characters (whitespace, for example).

In your case, you can do like this :

```
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(strHexNumber, 16);
```

Comment: Upvote for adding in the documentation snippet even though the answer is roughly the same as the accepted answer.  You submitted your answer 2 minutes after the accepted answer so thanks for the effort.